# How to search for values inside child/nested element with orderByChild() in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if the user for a user_id has a certain value in the `project_id` field inside the `interested_in` node. The key is same as the user_id field. I have used `orderByChild` with `equalTo` but it is returning null. I want to compare `project_id` value with `id`. Is it because I am not referencing the node correctly? Can anyone please take a quick look and help me?

```
     let usersRef = db.ref('users/' + this.user_id + '/interested_in');
          usersRef.orderByChild('project_id')
              .equalTo(id).on('value', function(snapshot){
                console.log(snapshot.val());
          });
```

[image: Firebase screenshot here]

Comment: At first glance the code and the data structure seem to match. Can you `console.log` the values of `this.user_id` and `id` in your code, to see if they match up to the values in the JSON? Please also check the logging output of your app, to see if there are any relevant message (for example around permissions).

Comment: So if the value of `id` does not match in any `project_id` , `snapshot.val()` will be null correct? and if there is a match, it will return an object in `snapshot.val()` .

Comment: The `snapshot` itself will never be null. But if there's no child node matching the query then `snapshot.exists()` returns `false`, and `snapshot.val()` returns `null`.